# JSON Schema: First Item of Array

Tags: arrays, json

I need a JSON array of arbitrary length. Each item in the array is a JSON object, they all have same keys and types.

**But the schema should make one exception: the first object doesn't need all keys, so schemas required list should be shorter for the first item.**

I tried schemas with "items" and "prefixItems" without luck. It seems that "prefixItems" will be ignored independently of draft version when used with "items". Because array can be of arbitrary length, I guess I cannot use multiple schemas with "items".

```
{
    "description": "Schema for array data",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-2020-12/schema#",
    "version": "0-0-6",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "data"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "array",
            "prefixItems": [{
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "name"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "name" : { "type" :"string" },
                    "age" : { "type" : "number" },
                    "city" : { "type" : "string" }  
                }
            }],
            "items": 
              {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "name", "age", "city"
                  
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "name" : { "type" :"string" },
                    "age" : { "type" : "number" },
                    "city" : { "type" : "string" } 
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

My data:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "name": "Tom"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ben",
            "age": 32,
            "city": "Berlin"
        },
        {       
            "name": "Mike", 
            "age": 40,
            "city": "Boston"
        } 
    ]
}
```

For validation I use:

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

https://jsonlint.com/

Validation of my example gives error for first item:
"Required properties are missing from object: age, city."

Comment: I came on here with the same problem: "items" eclipses "prefixItems". I'm using jsonschema cli version 3.2.0 as my validator. "prefixItems" w/o "items" in the schema for an array works fine.

Comment: I tried with this example https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation and replicated your issue.

Comment: But if I use prefixItem (w/o item) for the first object, how can I add a schema for all other objects?

Comment: according to my tests, you can't. it looks like a bug in the validator to me.

Comment: how about upvoting my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `additionalItems` instead of `items`.

Schema:

```
{
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
"type": "array",
"prefixItems": [
  { "type": "number" },
  { "type": "string" },
  { "enum": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"] },
  { "enum": ["NW", "NE", "SW", "SE"] }
],
"additionalItems": {
  "type": "number"
}
```

}

Data that validates:

```
[
1600,
"Pennsylvania",
"Avenue",
"NW",
1]
```

The issue you're running into is that the validators only support up to draft 7 of the standard, and using `items` the way we both want to was new in the 2019 draft. It's not supported yet.

Comment: When I copy paste you code into https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and make a negativ test, I get a false positive. Is it the validator that doesn't support v7?